# Reading .dat file in C missing / repeating records

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read a structure from a .dat file...
the first integer to be read is the no of readings 
then there is the data in following structure format

```
struct Oven
{
int rec_no; 
int temp; 
int status;
char string[10];
};
```

below is the method through which I read the file

```
int read_and_process_file()
{
    int counter;
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    struct Oven my_record; 

    ptr_myfile=fopen("data.dat","rt");

    //for no of readings
    fread(&no_of_readings,sizeof(no_of_readings),1,ptr_myfile);


        for ( counter=1; counter <= 50; counter++) 
        { 
              fread(&my_record,sizeof(struct Oven),1,ptr_myfile);

            name=my_record.string;

            printf("%d : ",my_record.rec_no);
            fprintf(ptr_myfile2,"%d : ",my_record.rec_no);
            printf("%d : ",my_record.temp);
            printf("%d : ",my_record.status);
            printf("%s\n",name);
        } 

    fclose(ptr_myfile);
   return 0; 
}
```

but i can't read more than 25 records after 25 it keeps on repeating the 25th record...

tried fseek but it skips some records... any help?

This is the output image

[image]

UPDATE (Wildplasser) And here is the first 0x200 bytes of the data (wich does look a bit irregular ...)

```
00000000  b8 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00  54 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |........T.......|
00000010  42 6f 62 00 cd cd cd cd  cd cd cd cd 01 00 00 00  |Bob.............|
00000020  4d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00 cd  |M.......CLOSED..|
00000030  cd cd cd cd 02 00 00 00  2e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00 cd  cd cd cd cd 03 00 00 00  |CLOSED..........|
00000050  5f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  48 61 72 72 79 00 cd cd  |_.......Harry...|
00000060  cd cd cd cd 04 00 00 00  44 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |........D.......|
00000070  48 61 72 72 79 00 cd cd  cd cd cd cd 05 00 00 00  |Harry...........|
00000080  63 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  4a 69 6c 6c 00 cd cd cd  |c.......Jill....|
00000090  cd cd cd cd 06 00 00 00  53 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |........S.......|
000000a0  4a 61 6d 65 73 00 cd cd  cd cd cd cd 07 00 00 00  |James...........|
000000b0  56 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00 cd  |V.......CLOSED..|
000000c0  cd cd cd cd 08 00 00 00  49 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........I.......|
000000d0  43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00 cd  cd cd cd cd 09 00 00 00  |CLOSED..........|
000000e0  53 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  42 6f 62 00 cd cd cd cd  |S.......Bob.....|
000000f0  cd cd cd cd 0d 0a 00 00  00 59 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........Y......|
00000100  00 43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00  cd cd cd cd cd 0b 00 00  |.CLOSED.........|
00000110  00 46 00 00 00 01 00 00  00 4a 69 6c 6c 00 cd cd  |.F.......Jill...|
00000120  cd cd cd cd cd 0c 00 00  00 38 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........8......|
00000130  00 43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00  cd cd cd cd cd 0d 00 00  |.CLOSED.........|
00000140  00 48 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00  |.H.......CLOSED.|
00000150  cd cd cd cd cd 0e 00 00  00 5e 00 00 00 01 00 00  |.........^......|
00000160  00 4a 61 6d 65 73 00 cd  cd cd cd cd cd 0f 00 00  |.James..........|
00000170  00 40 00 00 00 01 00 00  00 4a 69 6c 6c 00 cd cd  |.@.......Jill...|
00000180  cd cd cd cd cd 10 00 00  00 56 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........V......|
00000190  00 43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00  cd cd cd cd cd 11 00 00  |.CLOSED.........|
000001a0  00 43 00 00 00 01 00 00  00 4a 61 6d 65 73 00 cd  |.C.......James..|
000001b0  cd cd cd cd cd 12 00 00  00 60 00 00 00 01 00 00  |.........`......|
000001c0  00 42 6f 62 00 cd cd cd  cd cd cd cd cd 13 00 00  |.Bob............|
000001d0  00 5e 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00  |.^.......CLOSED.|
000001e0  cd cd cd cd cd 14 00 00  00 55 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........U......|
000001f0  00 43 4c 4f 53 45 44 00  cd cd cd cd cd 15 00 00  |.CLOSED.........|
```

Comment: you seem to read in no_of_readings then ignore it and use counter fixed at 50. Does your input file have more than 25 records? Your also not checking the return codes of the file operations for errors.

Comment: yes I have 3000 records at first I want to check for first 50 records, checking for fread i get 0 after 25th record, but i have more than 25..

Comment: I added the hexdump to the OQ. From this hexdump it is clear that after Bob there is a CRLF pair. The file probably has been transferred by FTP in ASCII mode or even worse: edited by a BillyBoyGatesEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on as your code snippet isn't complete, but here are some things I noticed:

- You don't seem to be using the read-in no_of_readings, and instead try to read 50 records. Since you don't check the return value of fread, your program just carries on using whatever the last successful fread read.
- You shouldn't be opening the file in text mode if you're not reading text. Line ending conversion could corrupt your data. Use "rb" instead (also the standard C way to open in text mode is just to omit the b, t is nonstandard).
- **edit:** On Windows reading a file in text mode interprets a ctrl-z byte (26) as end of file. This is why your reads stop after the 25th record.
- Reading/writing data directly to/from structs like this will result in data files that aren't portable. Better to serialise your struct into bytes manually.

Comment: I want to read only 50 records no_of_readings=3000 after reading the file.. so I am not using it. Using return value from fread I get 0 after the 25th record, that means fread is not getting records more than 25 why is that?

Comment: if I use rb instead of rt I get only 1st 10 records correctly

Comment: can please you add some more information about serializing of structs manually?

Comment: Are you writing the file in text mode too? If you are you'll get line ending conversion on rec_no 10 (ASCII '\n'). On Windows you'll get an extra 0x0d byte written that'll misalign all further records.

Comment: no i am reading that file only... using rt makes me read more than 10 records but in rb mode i can't get more than 10

Comment: Can you post the code that wrote data.dat? Or maybe a hex dump of the first part you are trying to read?

Comment: No I don't have that code that writes the file...yu can download the file form this link https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5T4nL_0pCoXVDlxc1FQc1ctSk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The file has an extra 0x0d byte on the 10th record, so looks like it was written in text mode too, which has resulted in corruption.

Comment: See edit. You need to be using binary mode, and your input file needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much frank for your valuable information helped me a lot, I am reading the file now in binary mode "rb". I have to read data from this file as it is so i am skipping that exta 0x0d byte... well the main problem is not with my code its with the file.. thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the return value of the fread to check for errors

```
       int size = fread(&my_record,sizeof(struct Oven),1,ptr_myfile);
       if (size != sizeof(struct Oven))
       {
          perror ("Error reading Line %d", counter);
          break;
       }
```

This should give an idea of what went wrong